# How to create a class to get latitude and longitude of user, using Google API - Android

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

I'm developing an Android app, and I need to get latitude and longitude of the user.

I googled and found that Google API is the best for this, and I found a tutorial on this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

How I don't need location updates (just click in a button, and get the location), I just copied this piece of code from tutorial:

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // UI elements
    private TextView lblLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

        // First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        // Show location button click listener
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     * */
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);

        } else {

            lblLocation
                    .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

and it worked!!!

But I want to create a method (in another class) that get the current location and return it (instead of doing this inside activity).

So, I modified what I did above, and finished with the following:

```
public class UserLocation implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public HashMap<String, Double> getUserLocation(Activity act) {
        HashMap<String, Double> getLocation = new HashMap<>();

        if (checkPlayServices(act)) {
            buildGoogleApiClient(act);
        }

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            getLocation.put("latitude", latitude);
            getLocation.put("longitude", longitude);

            return getLocation;

        } else {
            Log.i("FAIL: ", "(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating google api client object
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Activity act) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(act)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices(Activity act) {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(act);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i("Fail: ", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

And I call it from the main Activity this way:

```
HashMap<String, Double> userLoc = ul.getUserLocation(this);
ul.getUserLocation(getActivity());
```

But with this new class, I don't get the location... I debuged, and saw that mLastLocation is always null...

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the activity you get last location after Google API client connected and it is right. In `UserLocation` class you are trying to get location before connection established and it is wrong.

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)):

> If not connected null will be returned.

You need to move getting location in `onConnected()` method and somehow notify the activity. You can create callback for it or simply let the activity implement `ConnectionCallbacks` instead of `UserLocation`.